# RAII-style C++ class for linked list Nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, raii

I'm playing with linked lists as an exercise at the moment.

The examples I'm looking at in the [Cracking The Coding Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X) book have no LinkedList (manager) class, just Nodes, and you hang on to the head Node in your main function.

I looked up C++ implementations, but most seem to be more C-style than C++, i.e. not object-oriented. They use structs, no classes, and have a static method for deleting the list, which you need to explicitly remember to call. I wanted to write a sensible RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) style C++ class with sensible destructors to handle memory deallocation, and I wanted to use only a Node class (no LinkedList class).

The only way I saw to have this work was to have Node's destructor delete the next Node if there was one, but I've read that this kind of recursive delete is a bad idea, because you end up creating a callstack the same length as the linked list.

So to summarize my question:

- If writing an object-oriented class to handle linked lists in C++, do you have to have a LinkedList (manager) class which handles the deletion of the list nodes in its destructor?
- If not, how would you deal with destruction of Nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: The `std::list` in the C++ standard library *is* a list manager, that allocates and owns the nodes in the list. It also deallocates them when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If writing an object-oriented class to handle linked lists in C++, do you have to have a LinkedList (manager) class which handles the deletion of the list nodes in its destructor?

No, the structure is defined by the links between nodes, so there's no need for a separate manager object. It can sometimes be more convenient to have one, especially if you're designing a library like the STL and want all the containers to have a similar interface, but you can certainly implement a linked list with just a node type.

> If not, how would you deal with destruction of Nodes?

One way to avoid recursion is to remove each node from the list before deleting it, something like:

```
~node() {
    while (node * victim = next) {
        next = victim->next;
        victim->next = nullptr;
        delete victim;
    }
}
```